# Filtering based on the month someone was born

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently trying to create a query that filters on the month that someone was born but its returning errors.
I want it to display everyone who was born on 05 month.

```
SELECT "Person Names"."Full Name" saw_0,
       "Person"."Person Date Of Birth" saw_1  
  FROM "Workforce Management - Person Real Time"
 WHERE "Person"."Person Date Of Birth" = date '%-05-%'
```

Comment: What are the errors exactly? Please provide table definition as well.

Answer (score 1):

Considering `"Person"."Person Date Of Birth"` is of type `DATE` you could simply do:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR("Person"."Person Date Of Birth",'MM') = '05'
```

**Update:**

```
WHERE TO_CHAR("Person"."Person Date Of Birth",'MM') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM')
```

This will give you the people born in the current month.

Comment: Thanks will give this a try.Is there a way to make the month dynamically update looking to have a report run on the 1st of every month so It would be good if it auto updated the filter based on what month it is

Comment: Updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` followed by a string is a date literal. The string must have the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. The expression `date '%-05-%'` is hence syntactically incorrect.

You can, however, extract a month from a date:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "Person"."Person Date Of Birth") = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXTRACT` to check the month. In case your column is already of type date, this will do:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datecolumn) = 5;
```

If the column is of type varchar, you can cast it as date and then do the same:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE 
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(varcharcolumn,'dd.mm.yyyy')) = 5;
```

Please see a simple example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e3ea701f52709f81dcc17238dedd1b5)